# node-canvas works in Node but fails when required from PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, phantomjs, node-gyp

I have a PhantomJS app where I'd like to take a series of screenshots from a JS-driven page (via `page.renderBase64('PNG')`) and then stitch those screenshots into a GIF.

As far as I can tell, there's no way in Node to build a GIF out of pure base64 strings, and I'd really prefer not to write each frame to the disk and then go outside Node to stitch them together with ImageMagick or the like -- that would dramatically slow down the process. So my plan was to paint the base64 images onto a canvas and then add the canvas to a Node GIF generator.

While I can use [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/) in a Node environment with no problem, when I include `require('canvas')` in my Phantom script, it fails when I initiate a new Canvas object, spitting out the usual errors one sees when missing dependencies:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/node-canvas/build/Release/canvas'

  phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:299 in require
  phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js:263 in require
```

Part of the problem, I think, is that Phantom is running Node from a different environment where all the dependencies aren't present. But I don't quite understand how Node and PhantomJS different in their execution of Javascript. I'm not clear what `phantomjs://platform/bootstrap.js` is or whether it's something I can extend.

To be clear, I'm using the Phantom-Node bridge where I begin the script with `var page = require('webpage').create();`. I then execute the script using `phantomjs` from the command line.

**TL;DR:** Requiring C++-based Node module, node-canvas, from a PhantomJS script it fails, where it doesn't fail when run from Node. How are the environments different? Why do some Node modules work while others don't?

**Update:** I'm aware that I could just make a `<canvas>` element on the page being rendered by Phantom and use that, but that requires a lot of time-consuming back-and-forth between the sandboxed JS for the page and the script itself.

Comment: Also you will most likely have to recompile the native npm module to work with the version of node bundled with the phantom-node bridge. Some packages that include a bundled version of the node runtime provide tools for this (electron-rebuild). Which package are you using for the phantom-node interaction ?

Comment: I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1, which I believe is the latest. How do I figure out which version of Node it has baked in?

Comment: Are you using this npm package https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/ for interacting with phantomjs using node ?

Comment: I was actually just running `phantomjs` from the CLI and directly requiring `page`, but it seems like the bridge is better for marrying Node and Phantom?

Comment: For what you are trying to do that package might work better, i haven't looked at it in depth but it appears that it doesn't use a prebuilt bundled version of node.js and is more of just node API for phantomjs. you in theory you should be able to get a base64 string of the pages current visual state periodically and stitch together a gif using node-canvas.

Comment: I initially agreed, but then module is so Promise-heavy that writing and sort of involve code around the `page` module amounts to a looooong series of cascading `then`s :)

Comment: Could use async await 

Comment: Fair enough! But insofar as Phantom is **much** easier to use directly, is there a way to npm install a module using Phantom's built-in node instead of the default version on the machine?